# Java ternary (immediate if) evaluation

Tags: java, conditional-operator, short-circuiting

I can't find the relevant portion of the spec to answer this.
In a conditional operator statement in Java, are both the true and false arguments evaluated?

So could the following throw a NullPointerException

```
Integer test = null;

test != null ? test.intValue() : 0;
```

Comment: It's also something simple enough that you could just try it out and see what happens :)

Comment: Which gives you information on one particular instance.  Better to find what the standard says.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Since you wanted the spec, here it is (from [§15.25 Conditional Operator ? :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), the last sentence of the section):

> The operand expression not chosen is not evaluated for that particular evaluation of the conditional expression.

Answer (score 24):

I know it is old post, but look at very similar case and then vote me :P

Answering original question : only one operand is evaluated BUT:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    Integer A = null;
    Integer B = null;

    Integer chosenInteger = A != null ? A.intValue() : B;    
}
```

This test will throw `NullPointerException` always and in this case IF statemat is not equivalent to ?: operator.

The reason is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.25. The part about boxing/unboxing is embroiled, but it can be easy understood looking at:

> "If one of the second and third operands is of type `boolean` and the type of the other is of type `Boolean`, then the type of the conditional expression is `boolean`."

The same applies to `Integer.intValue()`

Best regards!

Comment: Interesting point, thanks Michal. Because A.intValue() is of type int, the reference to B must be auto unboxed. But it's null, so it throws NPE. In Java 8/Eclipse Luna with null analysis turned on, this test doesn't even compile!

Answer (score 8):

No, it couldn't.  That's the same as:

```
Integer test = null;
if ( test != null ) { 
    test = test.intValue();
}
else {
    test = 0;
}
```