# How to get the first non-null value in Java?

Tags: java, coalesce

Is there a Java equivalent of SQL's `COALESCE` function? That is, is there any way to return the first non-null value of several variables?

e.g.

```
Double a = null;
Double b = 4.4;
Double c = null;
```

I want to somehow have a statement that will return the first non-null value of `a`, `b`, and `c` - in this case, it would return `b`, or 4.4. (Something like the sql method - return `COALESCE(a,b,c)`). I know that I can do it explicitly with something like:

```
return a != null ? a : (b != null ? b : c)
```

But I wondered if there was any built-in, accepted function to accomplish this.

Comment: You shouldn't need a function like this as you geneally wouldn't calculate 'c' if 'b' has the answer you want. i.e. you wouldn't build a list of possible answers only to keep one.

Comment: Caveat: Not all RDBMS short circuit on COALESCE. Oracle only recently started doing it.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

No, there isn't.

The closest you can get is:

```
public static <T> T coalesce(T ...items) {
    for (T i : items) if (i != null) return i;
    return null;
}
```

For efficient reasons, you can handle the common cases as follows:

```
public static <T> T coalesce(T a, T b) {
    return a == null ? b : a;
}
public static <T> T coalesce(T a, T b, T c) {
    return a != null ? a : (b != null ? b : c);
}
public static <T> T coalesce(T a, T b, T c, T d) {
    return ...
}
```

The efficiency reason is that an array allocation will happen each time you invoke the `...` version of the method. This could be wasteful for hand-fulls of items, which I suspect will be common usage.

Comment: the efficiency reasons that i mentioned above is that an array allocation will happen each time you invoke the var arg version of the method. this could be wasteful for hand-fulls of items, which i suspect will be common usage.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. In that case I'll probably stick to the nested conditional operators in this case as it's the only time it has to be used and the user-defined method would be overkill...

Comment: I still would pull it out into a private helper method rather than leave a "scary looking" conditional block in the code - "what does that do?" that way, if you ever do need to use it again, you can use the refactoring tools in your IDE to move the method to the utility class. having the named method helps to document the intent of the code, which is always a good thing, IMO. (and the overhead of the non var-args version is probably barely measurable.)

Comment: Watch out: In `coalesce(a, b)`, if `b` is a complex expression and `a` is not `null`, `b` is still evaluated. This is not the case for the ?: conditional operator. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/978357/1402846).

Comment: this requires every argument to be precalculated before the call to coalesce, pointless for performance reasons

Comment: you should not use this function with expressions as there is no lazy evaluation in java ..... yet?

Comment: Hoping to be useful I integrated the comment from les2 in their answer itself

Answer (score 296):

**Apache Commons Lang 3**

[`ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(T, T)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#defaultIfNull(T,%20T))

or less efficient but for more potential values:

[`ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull%28T...%29)

**Java 8 Stream**

[`Stream.of(T...).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Comment: I was looking for the same but for strings, and found out that there are SpringUtils.firstNonBlank(T...) and SpringUtils.firstNonBlank(T...) methods.

Comment: Note that both methods listed here introduce performance implications due to extra objects allocation, unlike simple ternary operator or Guava's `MoreObjects.firstNonNull`.

Comment: `Stream.of(null,"a")` will not work since the `of` function is annotated with `@NonNull`

Comment: @pyropunk51 it's only `Stream.of(null)` which throws a null pointer exception. With more than one arguments any argument can be `null`, at least since Java 11.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77764610/227779 for more details about the Apache Commons `ObjectUtils` approach vs other methods (particularly if you are using Java 9, and are fine with exceptions if all values are `null`)

Answer (score 69):

If there are only two references to test and you are using Java 8, you could use

```
Object o = null;
Object p = "p";
Object r = Optional.ofNullable( o ).orElse( p );
System.out.println( r );   // p
```

If you import static Optional the expression is not too bad.

Unfortunately your case with "several variables" is not possible with an Optional-method. Instead you could use:

```
Object o = null;
Object p = null;
Object q = "p";

Optional<Object> r = Stream.of( o, p, q ).filter( Objects::nonNull ).findFirst();
System.out.println( r.orElse(null) );   // p
```

Comment: Possible without the use of optional:
`Object default = "some value"; Object res = ((res = getSomeNullable()) != null) ? res : default;
`

Answer (score 67):

If there are only two variables to check and you're using Guava, you can use [MoreObjects.firstNonNull(T first, T second)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull-T-T-).

Comment: Objects.firstNonNull only takes two arguments; there is no varargs equivalent in Guava. Also, it throws a NullPointerException if both args are null -- this may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Good comment, Jake. This NullPointerException often restricts Objects.firstNonNull usage. However, it's Guava's approach to avoid nulls at all.

Comment: That method is now deprecated, and the recommended alternative is [MoreObjects.firstNonNull](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T))

Comment: If NPE is undesired, then see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18741740/476716)

Answer (score 26):

Following on from LES2's answer, you can eliminate some repetition in the efficient version, by calling the overloaded function:

```
public static <T> T coalesce(T a, T b) {
    return a != null ? a : b;
}
public static <T> T coalesce(T a, T b, T c) {
    return a != null ? a : coalesce(b,c);
}
public static <T> T coalesce(T a, T b, T c, T d) {
    return a != null ? a : coalesce(b,c,d);
}
public static <T> T coalesce(T a, T b, T c, T d, T e) {
    return a != null ? a : coalesce(b,c,d,e);
}
```

Comment: +1 for pretty.  Not sure about the efficiency benefits over the simple loop, but if you're going to eke out any tiny efficiency this way, it might as well be pretty.

Comment: this way makes it much less painful and less error prone to write the overloaded variants!

Comment: The point of the efficient version was to not waste memory allocating an array by using `varargs`. Here, you're wasting memory by creating a stack frame for each nested `coalesce()` call. Calling `coalesce(a, b, c, d, e)` creates up to 3 stack frames to calculate.

Comment: Overloading hell

Answer (score 13):

This situation calls for some preprocessor. Because if you write a function (static method) which picks the first not null value, it evaluates all items. It is problem if some items are method calls (may be time expensive method calls). And this methods are called even if any item before them is not null.

Some function like this

```
public static <T> T coalesce(T ...items) …
```

should be used but before compiling into byte code there should be a preprocessor which find usages of this „coalesce function“ and replaces it with construction like

```
a != null ? a : (b != null ? b : c)
```

**Update 2014-09-02:**

Thanks to Java 8 and Lambdas there is possibility to have true coalesce in Java! Including the crucial feature: particular expressions are evaluated only when needed – if earlier one is not null, then following ones are not evaluated (methods are not called, computation or disk/network operations are not done).

I wrote an article about it [Java 8: coalesce – hledáme neNULLové hodnoty](https://blog.frantovo.cz/c/311/Java%208%3A%20coalesce%20%E2%80%93%20hled%C3%A1me%20neNULLov%C3%A9%20hodnoty) – (written in Czech, but I hope that code examples are understandable for everyone).

Comment: Nice article - it would be nice to have it English, though.

Comment: There's something about that blog page that doesn't work with Google Translate. :-(

Answer (score 9):

Since Java 9 there is builtin `Objects.requireNonNullElse` method for two parameter coalesce. That was the most useful for me.

Comment: Requires Android 30

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
public static <T> T coalesce(T... t) {
    return Stream.of(t).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28306286/5429049) response

Answer (score 5):

With Guava you can do:

```
Optional.fromNullable(a).or(b);
```

which doesn't throw NPE if both `a` and `b` are `null`.

EDIT: I was wrong, it does throw NPE. The correct way as commented by **Michal Čizmazia** is:

```
Optional.fromNullable(a).or(Optional.fromNullable(b)).orNull();
```

Comment: Hey, it does: `java.lang.NullPointerException: use Optional.orNull() instead of Optional.or(null)`

Comment: This does the trick: `Optional.fromNullable(a).or(Optional.fromNullable(b)).orNull()`

Answer (score 5):

How about using suppliers when you want to avoid evaluating some expensive method?

Like this:

```
public static <T> T coalesce(Supplier<T>... items) {
for (Supplier<T> item : items) {
    T value = item.get();
    if (value != null) {
        return value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
Double amount = coalesce(order::firstAmount, order::secondAmount, order::thirdAmount)
```

You can also use overloaded methods for the calls with two, three or four arguments.

In addition, you could also use streams with something like this:

```
public static <T> T coalesce2(Supplier<T>... s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s).map(Supplier::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: Why wrap the first argument in a `Supplier` if it will be inspected anyway? For the sake of uniformity?

Comment: This might be a bit old, but for completeness' sake: the approach by @Triqui does not necessarily evaluate all the parameters passed to `coalesce` - that's the point of the parameters being of type `Supplier`. They are evaluated only when `get()` is called - if the first parameter matches the criteria, the rest need not be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completness, the "several variables" case is indeed possible, though not elegant at all.  For example, for variables `o`, `p`, and `q`:

```
Optional.ofNullable( o ).orElseGet(()-> Optional.ofNullable( p ).orElseGet(()-> q ) )
```

Please note the use of `orElseGet()` attending to the case that `o`, `p`, and `q` are not variables but expressions either expensive or with undesired side-effects.

In the most general case `coalesce(e[1],e[2],e[3],...,e[N])`

```
coalesce-expression(i) ==  e[i]  when i = N
coalesce-expression(i) ==  Optional.ofNullable( e[i] ).orElseGet(()-> coalesce-expression(i+1) )  when i < N
```

This can generate expressions excessively long.  However, if we are trying to move to a world without `null`, then `v[i]` are most probably already of type `Optional<String>`, as opposed to simply `String`.  In this case,

```
result= o.orElse(p.orElse(q.get())) ;
```

or in the case of expressions:

```
result= o.orElseGet(()-> p.orElseGet(()-> q.get() ) ) ;
```

Furthermore, if you are also moving to a functional-declarative style, `o`, `p`, and `q` should be of type `Supplier<String>` like in:

```
Supplier<String> q= ()-> q-expr ;
Supplier<String> p= ()-> Optional.ofNullable(p-expr).orElseGet( q ) ;
Supplier<String> o= ()-> Optional.ofNullable(o-expr).orElseGet( p ) ;
```

And then the whole `coalesce` reduces simply to `o.get()`.

For a more concrete example:

```
Supplier<Integer> hardcodedDefaultAge= ()-> 99 ;
Supplier<Integer> defaultAge= ()-> defaultAgeFromDatabase().orElseGet( hardcodedDefaultAge ) ;
Supplier<Integer> ageInStore= ()-> ageFromDatabase(memberId).orElseGet( defaultAge ) ;
Supplier<Integer> effectiveAge= ()-> ageFromInput().orElseGet( ageInStore ) ;
```

`defaultAgeFromDatabase()`, `ageFromDatabase()`, and `ageFromInput()` would already return `Optional<Integer>`, naturally.

And then the `coalesce` becomes `effectiveAge.get()` or simply `effectiveAge` if we are happy with a `Supplier<Integer>`.

IMHO, with Java 8 we will see more and more code structured like this, as it's extremely self-explainatory and efficient at the same time, especially in more complex cases.

I do miss a class `Lazy<T>` that invokes a `Supplier<T>` only one time, but lazily, as well as consistency in the definition of `Optional<T>` (i.e. `Optional<T>`-`Optional<T>` operators, or even `Supplier<Optional<T>>`).

Answer (score 2):

(Similar to other answers, but I wanted to more exhaustively describe the differences between Guava's `MoreObjects.firstNonNull()`, Apache Commons Lang 3 `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull()` and the `java.util.Objects.requireNonNullElse()` and `requireNonNullElseGet()` methods introduced in Java 9.)

This answer is long - see the TL;DR at the end if you are want to just skip to the summary.

### Guava `MoreObjects.firstNonNull(T, T)`

Guava's [`MoreObjects.firstNonNull(T, T)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull-T-T-) is described like this. The important part is the `@throws NullPointerException if both {@code first} and {@code second} are null`. This method **requires** that either one of the objects are non-null

> **`public static <T> T firstNonNull​(@CheckForNull T first, @CheckForNull T second)`**
>
> Returns the first of two given parameters that is not null, if either is, or otherwise throws a `NullPointerException`.
>
> To find the first non-null element in an iterable, use `Iterables.find(iterable, Predicates.notNull())`. For varargs, use `Iterables.find(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, ...), Predicates.notNull())`, static importing as necessary.
>
> **Note:** if first is represented as an `Optional`, this can be accomplished with first.or(second). That approach also allows for lazy evaluation of the fallback instance, using first.or(supplier).
>
> **Java 9 users:** use java.util.Objects.requireNonNullElse(first, second)` instead.
>
> **Returns:**
> `first` if it is non-`null`; otherwise second if it is non-`null`
>
> **Throws**:
> `java.lang.NullPointerException` - if both `first` and `second` are `null`
>
> **Since:**
> 18.0 (since 3.0 as `Objects.firstNonNull())`.

### Apache Commons Lang 3 `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull()` and `defaultIfNull(T, T)`

[`ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull%28T...%29) on the other hand, has a much more "relaxed" handling of null values. If all values are null, well, then the method simply returns `null`. For some cases, this might be preferable (as long as the calling code handles `null` return values properly).

Also note that this takes a `T...` variable argument parameter, so it can be used with more than two parameters, unlike the other options.

> **`public static <T> T firstNonNull(T... values)`**
>
> Returns the first value in the array which is not `null`. If all the values are `null` or the array is `null` or empty then `null` is returned.
>
> `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(null, null)      = null`
> `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(null, "")        = ""`
> `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(null, null, "")  = ""`
> `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(null, "zz")      = "zz"`
> `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull("abc", *)        = "abc"`
> `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(null, "xyz", *)  = "xyz"`
> `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(Boolean.TRUE, *) = Boolean.TRUE`
> `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull()                = null`
>
> **Type Parameters:**
> `T` - the component type of the array
>
> **Parameters:**
> `values` - the values to test, may be `null` or empty
>
> **Returns:**
> the first value from values which is not `null`, or `null` if there are no non-`null` values
>
> **Since:**
> 3.0

The [`ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(T, T)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#defaultIfNull(T,%20T)) method also exists, and has similar `null` semantics, but is slightly more optimized for the two-parameter scenario.

#### JDK `java.util.Objects.requireNonNullElse` and `requireNonNullElseGet` methods

[`Objects.requireNonNullElse(T, T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-) has the following semantics. It matches the Guava `MoreObjects.firstNonNull()` method quite closely, it should be pretty much a drop-in replacement for that method.

> **`public static <T> T requireNonNullElse​(T obj, T defaultObj)`**
>
> Returns the first argument if it is non-`null` and otherwise returns the non-`null` second argument.
>
> **Type Parameters:**
> `T` - the type of the reference
>
> **Parameters:**
> `obj` - an object
> `defaultObj` - a non-`null` object to return if the first argument is `null`
>
> **Returns:**
> the first argument if it is non-`null` and otherwise the second argument if it is non-`null`
>
> **Throws:**
> `NullPointerException` - if both `obj` is `null` and `defaultObj` is `null`
>
> **Since:**
> 9

Finally, the [`Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(T obj, Supplier<? extends T> supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet-T-java.util.function.Supplier-) method. It can be useful if creating the fallback value is a more heavy operation that you want to avoid if `obj` is non-`null`.

> **`public static <T> T requireNonNullElseGet​(T obj, Supplier<? extends T> supplier)`**
>
> Returns the first argument if it is non-`null` and otherwise returns the non-`null` value of `supplier.get()`.
>
> **Type Parameters:**
> `T` - the type of the first argument and return type
>
> **Parameters:**
> `obj` - an object
> `supplier` - of a non-`null` object to return if the first argument is `null`
>
> **Returns:**
> the first argument if it is non-`null` and otherwise the value from `supplier.get()` if it is non-`null`
>
> **Throws:**
> `NullPointerException` - if both `obj` is `null` and either the `supplier` is `null` or the `supplier.get()` value is `null`
>
> **Since:**
> 9

### TL;DR

- If one of the parameters must not be `null`, use [`Objects.requireNonNullElse(T, T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-)
- If one of the parameters must not be `null` and you want to use a `Supplier` for the fallback (for performance/GC reasons), use [`Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(T obj, Supplier<? extends T> supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet-T-java.util.function.Supplier-)
- If one or both of the parameters can be `null` and Apache Commons Lang 3 is an acceptable dependency, use [`ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(T, T)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#defaultIfNull(T,%20T))
- If you are using more than two parameters and Apache Commons Lang 3 is fine, use [`ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull%28T...%29) but **please be aware** that `null` values can sneak through using this approach. You might want to wrap the result in a `Objects.requireNonNullElse()` call or some other `null`-guard to avoid NPE at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
firstNonNull = FluentIterable.from(
    Lists.newArrayList( a, b, c, ... ) )
        .firstMatch( Predicates.notNull() )
            .or( someKnownNonNullDefault );
```

Java ArrayList conveniently allows null entries and this expression is consistent regardless of the number of objects to be considered. (In this form, all the objects considered need to be of the same type.)

Answer (score -2):

```
Object coalesce(Object... objects)
{
    for(Object o : object)
        if(o != null)
            return o;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: God I hate generics.  I saw what yours meant right off the bat.  I had to look at @LES2's twice to figure out that he was doing the same thing (and probably "better")!  +1 for clarity

Comment: Yeah, generics are the way to go. But I'm not all that familiar with the intricacies.

Comment: Time to learn generics :-). There is little difference between @LES2's example and this, other than T instead of Object. -1 for building a function which will force casting the return value back to Double. Also for naming a Java method in all-caps, which may be fine in SQL, but isn't good style in Java.

Comment: I realize that all-caps is bad practice. I was just showing the OP how to write a function under the name they requested. Agreed, the cast back to `Double` is far from ideal. I just wasn't aware that static functions could be given type parameters. I thought it was just classes.