# Is there an equal for the c# null coalescing operator in java?

Tags: java, nullable, null-coalescing-operator

I searched a while for an equal for C# 'nullable' in java and found that one of the closest ways is to use the wrapper classes; now I want to know is there an equal for the c# null coalescing operator (??) in java? (of course except an ordinary 'if' statement)

Comment: That is really cool and I want it, but sadly, no, there is no such thing in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the first non-null value in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768054/how-to-get-the-first-non-null-value-in-java)

Comment: Indeed the 'null' is very common in programming and it's very strange that there is such a big gap in java.

Comment: @AymenDaoudi: As I already said I asked for a way other than if statements.(no doubt there is not much difference between the ' ? : ' operator and an 'if' statement)

Comment: I also wish Java had a ?. operator where `a?.foo()` only invokes `foo()` and returns its return value if a is not null, otherwise just returns null.  Likewise for field access: `a?.someField` would evaluate to null if a is null.

Comment: or an inverse of ??: `a ?=> b` evaluates to null if a is null, and evaluates to b if a is not null.  That way you could do things like `Integer i = s ?=> Integer.parseInt(s);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direct answer, no it doesn't exist in java

Comment: Is there a way to ask the Oracle for the reason,if you are so sure?

Comment: I've asked the oracle, and it revealed to me this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html there, are all operators you can find in java and i can't find any coalescing operator, unless you use a ternary or an if-else statement which I guess you're not looking for, as said in another answer here, Guava did the same thing making of that a merhod, If Google made a method to fill that gap, that means that that gap really exists, hope this explains how sure I'm.

Comment: It actually exists in Android Data Binding framework.

Comment: Igor, can you provide a link please ?

Answer (score 6):

No there isn't a null coalescing operator, however; there is a pattern that can be used in Java 8 that essentially does the same thing. Just wrap the result of an operation in an Optional and then call the orElse method

```
final String myString = Optional.ofNullable(resultSet.getString(1))
                                .orElse("default");
```

Comment: I really like this answer. You can also use the helpful `orElseGet(Supplier<T>)` method as well with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Guava provide an [`Objects.firstNonNull`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#firstNonNull%28T,%20T%29).

Comment: It seems useful but with huge overhead for a simple check!

Comment: Yes if you just need that functionality it's clearly an overhead