# Multiple null checks in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have the below code which is bit ugly for multiple null checks.

```
String s = null;

if (str1 != null) {
    s = str1;
} else if (str2 != null) {
    s = str2;
} else if (str3 != null) {
    s = str3;
} else {
    s = str4;
}
```

So I tried using `Optional.ofNullable` like below, but its still difficult to understand if someone reads my code. what  is the best approach to do that in Java 8.

```
String s = Optional.ofNullable(str1)
                   .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(str2)
                                   .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(str3)
                                                   .orElse(str4)));
```

In Java 9, we can use `Optional.ofNullable`with `OR`, But in Java8 is there any other approach ?

Comment: Java9 `or` syntax         `String s = Optional.ofNullable(str1)
                .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(str2))
                .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(str3))
                .orElse(str4);` looks not as good as the `Stream.of` I would sya.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable` is in Java-8 only, i guess.

Comment: This was what the elvis operator should do easily.  I think it is a good thing it wasn't introduced as it makes it easier to work with null values which I think is the wrong way to go.

Comment: I know the user is asking for Java-8 specific solution, but on a general note, I would go with `StringUtils.firstNonBlank()`

Comment: Problem is, Java 8/streams isn't the best solution for this.  That code really smells like a refactor is in order but without more context it's really hard to tell.  For starters--why aren't three objects that are probably so closely  related not already in a collection?

Comment: @MohamedAneesA would have provided the best answer (as a comment) but didn't specify the source of StringUtils in this case.  At any rate, if you HAVE to have these as a bunch of separate strings, coding it as a vargs method like "firstNonBlank" is ideal, the syntax inside will be an array making a simple for-each loop with a return on finding a non-null value trivial and obvious.  In this case, java 8 streams are an attractive nuisance.  they tempt you to inline and complicate something that should be a simple method/loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2768054/31782

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You may do it like so:

```
String s = Stream.of(str1, str2, str3)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(str4);
```

Comment: This.  Think in what you need, not what you have.

Comment: How much is the speed overhead? Creating Stream objects, calling 4 methods, creating temporary arrays (`{str1, str2, str3}`) look like much slower than a local `if` or `?:`, which the Java runtime can optimize. Is there some Stream-specific optimization in `javac` and the Java runtime which makes it as fast as `?:`? If not, I won't recommend this solution in performance-critical code.

Comment: @pts this is very likely to be slower than `?:` code and I'm sure you should avoid it in performance-critical code. It's however much more readable and you should recommend it in non-performance-critical code IMO, which I'm sure makes more than 99% of code.

Comment: @pts There are no Stream specific optimizations, neither in `javac` nor in the runtime. This does not preclude the general optimizations, like inlining all of the code, followed by eliminating redundant operations. In principle, the end result could be as efficient as the plain conditional expressions, however, it’s rather unlikely that it ever gets there, as the runtime would spend the necessary effort only on the hottest code paths.

Comment: @pts The creation and reclamation of small objects whose constructors do little explicit work is cheap, especially on modern
JVM implementations. Creating additional objects to enhance the clarity, simplicity, or power of a program is generally a good thing. There's a deep truth about optimization: it is easy to do more harm than good, especially if you optimize prematurely. So unless your application is performance stringent, you can use this approach with out any hesitation.

Comment: Great solution! To increase readability a little bit I would suggest to add `str4` to the parameters of `Stream.of(...)` and use `orElse(null)` in the end.

Comment: here findFirst() and findAny() will return the same, what if we have more than one not null;

Answer (score 74):

How about ternary conditional operator?

```
String s = 
    str1 != null ? str1 : 
    str2 != null ? str2 : 
    str3 != null ? str3 : str4
;
```

Comment: actually, he's looking for "the best approach to do this in Java8". This approach can be used in Java8, so it all just depends on what the OP means by "the best", and on which grounds he bases the decision of what is better on.

Comment: I usually dislike nested ternaries, but this looks pretty clean.

Comment: This is a huge pain to parse for anyone who isn't reading nested ternary operators every day.

Comment: @Cubic: If you think it's hard to parse, write a comment like `// take first non-null of str1..3`.  Once you know what it does, it becomes easy to see how.

Comment: @Cubic Yet, this is a **simple** repeated pattern. Once you parsed line 2, you've parsed the entire thing, no matter how many cases are included. And once you are done, you've learned to express a similar selection of ten different cases in a brief, and relatively simple manner. The next time you'll see a `?:` ladder, you'll know what it does. (Btw, functional programmers know this as `(cond ...)` clauses: It's always a guard followed by the appropriate value to use when the guard is true.)

Answer (score 35):

You can also use a loop:

```
String[] strings = {str1, str2, str3, str4};
for(String str : strings) {
    s = str;
    if(s != null) break;
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Current answers are nice but you really should put that in a utility method:

```
public static Optional<String> firstNonNull(String... strings) {
    return Arrays.stream(strings)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst();
}
```

That method has been in my `Util` class for years, makes code much cleaner:

```
String s = firstNonNull(str1, str2, str3).orElse(str4);
```

You can even make it generic:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Optional<T> firstNonNull(T... objects) {
    return Arrays.stream(objects)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .findFirst();
}

// Use
Student student = firstNonNull(student1, student2, student3).orElseGet(Student::new);
```

Comment: FWIW, in SQL, this function is called [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL), so i call it that in my code too. Whether that works for you depends how much you like SQL, really.

Comment: If you're going to put it in a utility method you might as well make it efficient.

Comment: @GustavoSilva Todd probably means that, this being a utility method of mine, there's no point in using `Arrays.stream()` when I can do the same with a `for` and a `!= null`, which is more efficient. And Todd would be right. However, when I coded this method I was looking for a way of doing this using Java 8 features, just like OP, so there's that.

Comment: @GustavoSilva Yeah that's basically it: if you're going to be putting this is a util function concerns about clean code aren't that important anymore, and so you might as well use a faster version.

Answer (score 13):

I use a helper function, something like

```
T firstNonNull<T>(T v0, T... vs) {
  if(v0 != null)
    return v0;
  for(T x : vs) {
    if (x != null) 
      return x;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then this kind of code can be written as

```
String s = firstNonNull(str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

Comment: Why the extra `v0` parameter?

Comment: @tobias_k The extra parameter when using varargs is the idiomatic way in Java to require 1 or more arguments rather than 0 or more. (See item 53 of Effective Java, Ed. 3., which uses `min` as an example.) I am less convinced that this is appropriate here.

Comment: @Nick Yes, I guessed as much, but the function would work just as well (in fact behave exactly the same) without it.

Comment: One of the key reasons for passing an extra first argument is to be explicit about the behaviour when passed an array. In this case, I want `firstNonNull(arr)` to return arr if it is not null. If it was `firstNonNull(T... vs)` it would instead return the first non-null entry in arr.

Answer (score 4):

A solution which can be applied to as many element as you want can be :

```
Stream.of(str1, str2, str3, str4)
      .filter(Object::nonNull)
      .findFirst()
      .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new)
```

---

You could imagine a solution like below, but the first one ensures `non nullity` for all of the elements

```
Stream.of(str1, str2, str3).....orElse(str4)
```

Comment: orElse `str4` inspite of it being a null actually

Comment: @nullpointer Or `orElseNull`, which amounts to the same if `str4` is null.

Answer (score 3):

You can also lump up all the Strings into an array of String then do a for loop to check and break from the loop once it's assigned.
Assuming s1, s2, s3, s4 are all Strings.

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {s1, s2, s3};


s = s4;

for (String value : arrayOfStrings) {
    if (value != null) { 
        s = value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Edited to throw in condition for default to s4 if none is assigned.

Comment: You have omitted `s4` (or `str4`), which is to supposed be assigned to `s` in the end, even if it is null.

Answer (score 2):

Method based and simple.

```java
String getNonNull(String def, String ...strings) {
    for(int i=0; i<strings.length; i++)
        if(strings[i] != null)
             return s[i];
    return def;
}
```

And use it as:

```java
String s = getNonNull(str4, str1, str2, str3);
```

It's simple to do with arrays and looks pretty.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apache Commons Lang 3 then it can be written like this:

```java
String s = ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

Use of [`ObjectUtils.firstNonNull(T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#firstNonNull%28T...%29) was taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18741740/11733759). Different approaches were also presented in related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2768054/11733759).

Answer (score 0):

Using of a **for loop** will be the most suitable solution, as all beginner and experienced developers have enough knowledge of Loops. It's quite simple, first make an array, and then check the entries one by one. If any nonNull string found then stop the loop, and proceed to the results.

```
String[] myData = {s1, s2, s3, s4};
String s = null;

for (String temp : myData) {
    if (temp != null) { 
        s = temp;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now you can track the nonNull value of the string, or can check if all strings were null, by using the below code.

```
if(s != null)
    System.out.println(s);
else
    System.out.println("All Strings are null");
```