# Java Is there any elegant way to assign a default value to Number if that Number is null

Tags: java, null, numbers

Is there a way to assign a default value to a derived class of Number, that can be passed through an int?

I am looking for an implementation for:

```
public <N extends Number> N getNumberWithDefault( N number, int defaultNumber );
```

I know it would be easy with:

```
public <N extends Number> N getNumberWithDefault(N number, Class<N> clazz, String defaultNumber) {
    N result = number;
    if (result == null) {
        try {
            result = clazz.cast(clazz.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, defaultNumber));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error assigning default", ex);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But it does not seem elegant at all.
Is there any way to improve it?

### UPDATE

What I wanted to know is if something like this can be done:

```
public <N extends Number> N getNumberWithDefault( N number ) {
    return getNumberWithDefault( number, 1 );
}
```

Then, the same function (getNumberWithDefault(number)), could be used for all classes.

Although I think that may be possible that that way to proceed is not possible in Java

Comment: IMO, a more elegant solution would be to use `N` as the type of `defaultNumber`.  This allows you to get rid of the `clazz` parameter.  But I can't think of a more elegant way to do a `valueOf` conversion in a generic context.

Comment: The signature of this method is impossible to honour. The function returns an unknown N and you want the return value to be int by default? Remove generics and return just `Number`, and also , take `Number`, then you can do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have just updated my question to be more specific.
May be Renato's answer is the good one (+1). I will keep in mind that it is impossible to create that function. (Generics was needed, as I wanted to return the same type as the input parameter, although with this signature the input parameter was allowed to be just Number, and in that case, I think the function would fail to guess the return type)

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768054

Answer (score 1):

The type-safe way, though not elegant, is to use overloading instead of generics.

Advantage is that the default value can be non-`int`, if needed.

```java
public Byte getNumberWithDefault(Byte number, int defaultNumber) {
    return (number != null ? number : Byte.valueOf((byte) defaultNumber));
}
public Short getNumberWithDefault(Short number, int defaultNumber) {
    return (number != null ? number : Short.valueOf((short) defaultNumber));
}
public Integer getNumberWithDefault(Integer number, int defaultNumber) {
    return (number != null ? number : Integer.valueOf(defaultNumber));
}
public Long getNumberWithDefault(Long number, long defaultNumber) {
    return (number != null ? number : Long.valueOf(defaultNumber));
}
public Float getNumberWithDefault(Float number, float defaultNumber) {
    return (number != null ? number : Float.valueOf(defaultNumber));
}
public Double getNumberWithDefault(Double number, double defaultNumber) {
    return (number != null ? number : Double.valueOf(defaultNumber));
}
public BigInteger getNumberWithDefault(BigInteger number, long defaultNumber) {
    return (number != null ? number : BigInteger.valueOf(defaultNumber));
}
public BigDecimal getNumberWithDefault(BigDecimal number, double defaultNumber) {
    return (number != null ? number : BigDecimal.valueOf(defaultNumber));
}
```

---

### UPDATE

For the updated question, where the default value is hardcoded as `1`, the answer is the same.

```java
public Byte getNumberWithDefault(Byte number) {
    return (number != null ? number : Byte.valueOf((byte) 1));
}
public Short getNumberWithDefault(Short number) {
    return (number != null ? number : Short.valueOf((short) 1));
}
public Integer getNumberWithDefault(Integer number) {
    return (number != null ? number : Integer.valueOf(1));
}
public Long getNumberWithDefault(Long number) {
    return (number != null ? number : Long.valueOf(1L));
}
public Float getNumberWithDefault(Float number) {
    return (number != null ? number : Float.valueOf(1f));
}
public Double getNumberWithDefault(Double number) {
    return (number != null ? number : Double.valueOf(1d));
}
public BigInteger getNumberWithDefault(BigInteger number) {
    return (number != null ? number : BigInteger.ONE);
}
public BigDecimal getNumberWithDefault(BigDecimal number) {
    return (number != null ? number : BigDecimal.ONE);
}
```

Comment: that's actually pretty neat. I was thinking to do something with Method Handles, but this is much nicer, to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice solution, but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I have just updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to solve this is to change the signature of your method to

```java
public <N extends Number> N getNumberWithDefault( N number, N defaultNumber )
```

That is, the defaultNumber has to be of the same type as number.

Of course, then its simple:

```java
public <N extends Number> N getNumberWithDefault( N number, N defaultNumber ){
   return number != null ? number : defaultNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice solution, but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I have just updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: Although your answer also seems to be good, as you suggest to change the method signature to the most similar to the one I propossed (+1)