# PHP comparison nature - adaptive or oblivious?

Tags: php, comparison, logic

What is the nature of PHP in terms of logical operators? Suppose `a` and `b` are expressions:

```
if (a || b) { body }
```

Which of the following is true?

- PHP always evaluates truthfulness of a and b. (Oblivious nature), OR
- PHP doesn't evaluate truthfulness of b if a is true (Adaptive nature and memory optimized: PHP evaluates truthfulness of b only if a is false).

Comment: It would take you 10 seconds to answer your own question *if only* you tested it.

Comment: how? i can't test it. It's internals of language.

Comment: This question isn't about comparisons. It's about boolean operators.

Comment: no, it's all about of algorithm and dynamics of language.

Comment: You can't test: `if (a() || b())` - well, then look at least into the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP short circuit lazy evaluation, where is it in the php.net manual?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220919/php-short-circuit-lazy-evaluation-where-is-it-in-the-php-net-manual)

Comment: No, it's not. This has to do with short-circuit evaluation of the boolean (logical) operators.  Are you asking if PHP somehow caches the result of the conditional? How would that ever work then, they are variables?!

Comment: **How is this not testable?** An example of how to prove this is *right in the PHP manual!*

Comment: Perfectly testable and googlable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694733/php-short-circuit-evaluation)

Comment: @Praveen: your use of "adaptive" and "oblivious" to describe the behavior of logical operators is not one I've seen before. Please cite your source.

Comment: @outis, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7bgwYkgC4c, at minute 36.45.

Comment: @Praveen: In written form please, not some audio, preferable a published book.

Comment: @harke, MIT.Introduction.to.Algorithms.3rd.Edition Page 227. "An oblivious compare-exchange algorithm operates solely by a sequence of prespecified compare-exchange operations".i may be using term 'oblivious'wrongly for a simple comparison, but for sorting algortihms this type of blind comparison is told as oblivious.

Comment: Wow, I still don't know what you are talking about. Compare-exchange sounds like the x86 CMPXCHG instruction? Either way I feel like you are getting topics gravely mixed up. Someone correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Jonathon.. this is not a math theorem that u want me to prove, sorry i can't help you.SEARCH meaning of Oblivious nature in dictionary or read the complete book that i pointed out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<?php

if (print_r("Why don't you try?") || print_r("It's not that hard")) { }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also known as [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_languages), which [PHP uses for logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

For those not wanting to click the link above, this is adapted from the PHP manual:

```
// --------------------
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());

function foo() { echo "PHP.net Lies!"; }
```

There are numerous SO questions on this as well:

- [PHP short circuit lazy evaluation, where is it in the php.net manual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220919/php-short-circuit-lazy-evaluation-where-is-it-in-the-php-net-manual)
- [PHP Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694733/php-short-circuit-evaluation)

Also, this has negligible impact on memory usage, provided nothing is being allocated in the code that is short-circuited.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by adaptive vs oblivious. Please cite something that explains.