# How far does PHP check if statements?

Tags: php, testing, if-statement

When there is an if statement like:

```
if (var1 == "test" || var2 == "test")
```

will PHP stop testing when var1 is already tested true and therefore not test var2? I know C# doesn't but im not too sure about PHP

Comment: It will stop if the `var1 == 'test'` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks bro, i also corrected the funny mistake in the question haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if the specific operators [**short-circuit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220919/php-short-circuit-lazy-evaluation-where-is-it-in-the-php-net-manual), which the boolean operators do.

Comment: @ignacia Vazquez-Abrams so in this case since I'm using || when var1 is tested false, var2 won't get tested right?

Comment: @Michael: When `var1 == 'test'` is `TRUE` it will stop, if it's `FALSE` it needs to test `var2 == 'test'`.