# In Java's ternary operator, can the first argument be evaluated even if the expression resulted in a false value?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I found an unusual bug in my code recently through random ad-hoc testing.  So, I made a test case for it.

Here is my test case:

```
 SampleRequest request = new SampleRequest();
    request.setA(null);
    request.setB(null);
    assertEquals(null, request.getAOrB());
```

A and B are defined as java.lang.Integer types and have direct setter methods to set their values into the request.

There is also an enumeration involved.  It has a primitive integer value, and a method that's used in this code.  I'll post the relevant portions here:

```
enum Swapper {
public int c;
Swapper findSwapperToUse(final int a) {
   for(Swapper swapper : values()) {
       if(swapper.c == a) {
          return swapper;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
}
```

Now, here's the method that is being confusing.  Invoking the test method on that method results in a NPE, but on the last line of the method.

```
    public class SampleRequest {
    private Integer A;
    private Integer B;

    public void setA(final Integer A) {
        this.A = A;
    }

    public void setB(final Integer B) {
        this.B = B;
    }


public Integer getAOrB() {
    return A != null ? Swapper.findSwapperToUse(A).c
         : B;
}
}
```

In the test, both A and B are set to null.  Therefore, A != null returns false.  However, I get a NullPointerException at the line number for the : B line.

My guess is that for some reason the first expression, Swapper.findSwapperToUse(A).c, is being evaluated, and therefore the A.intValue() is invoked via autoboxing, resulting in a NullPointerException on the null value.  Through debugging, it's known that findSwapperToUse() is not invoked.

However, according to this questionthis should not happen:
[Java ternary (immediate if) evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978324/java-short-style-if-evaluation)

> The operand expression not chosen is not evaluated for that particular evaluation of the conditional expression.

Returning a null (B) will not result in a NullPointerException - it's perfectly fine to return a null result here.

What the heck is going on?

EDIT: I forgot to add that I altered the code to avoid this by using a straight up if statement - the following code does work as expected:

```
public Integer getAOrB() {
    if(A != null) {
        return Swapper.findSwapperToUse(A).c;
    }
    return B;
}
```

Comment: The code you've given wouldn't compile (e.g. a lack of return type). Please give a short but *complete* example, and we'll see what's going on.

Comment: How can you be _ABSOLUTELY_ certain that A is null?

Comment: I provided the return type, sorry - it was Swapper.  @Thor - because of the test (request.setA(null), request.setB(null))

Comment: @MetroidFan, still, a complete (compilable) example is needed. I couldn't reproduce it using only relevant parts of your code. Could be because of the difference in Java versions, but could be because the bug isn't where you expect it to be. For example, you may have both setA() and setB() actually setting the value of B only due to some copy-paste.

Comment: It's not something to do with autoboxing is it? Somehow the VM is trying to cast a null into an Integer? I'm clutching at straws a bit because I can't see anything else in your code, but I thought I'd throw it into the pot!

Comment: I thought that the ternary example would get compiled to be equivalent to the if else example. Weird.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I guess the problem is caused by the fact that compiler infers the type of the whole expression

```
A != null ? Swapper.findSwapperToUse(A).c : B
```

as `int` from the type of `Swapper.c`, and therefore tries to apply unboxing conversion to `B`.

Here is the related excerpt from [the JLS, §15.25](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25):

> - Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are convertible
>     (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
>   - ...
>   - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand
>       types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the
>       second and third operands. **Note that binary numeric promotion performs
>       unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)** and value set conversion (§5.1.13).

You can prevent it by adding the following cast:

```
A != null ? (Integer) Swapper.findSwapperToUse(A).c : B
```

Comment: That's ridiculous, but it's what it was!  Thanks.

Comment: :(  There should be a compiler flag to disable autoboxing to catch these things.

Comment: @MetroidFan, the funny thing is that your stack trace actually pointed at the correct line. When I reproduced this on my PC I got NPE at the `A != null` line instead. I guess it just pointed to the statement where it happened, not the actual line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `findSwapperToUse` method is returning null, and you can't do `null.c`.

To make sure of this, I would change your code to read:

```
public Integer getAOrB() {
    if(A != null) {
        Swapper foundSwapper = Swapper.findSwapperToUse(A);
        return foundSwapper.c;
    }
    return B;
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it wouldn't explain the bit at the bottom of the question.

Comment: The OP said explicitly that this method is not invoked. Which is no surprise considering that A is null, so it can't be an argument to a function accepting `int`.

Comment: @Sergey oops missed that bit :)