# What does the null ? 0 and null ? null mean in android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, baseadapter

I have see the following code , but I don't know what it mean.

```
    public class FileListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater ;
        private ArrayList<FileNode> mFileList ;
        private Map<Integer, Boolean> mSelectMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
                    ．
                    ．
                    ．
        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return mFileList == null ? 0 : mFileList.size() ;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return mFileList == null ? null : mFileList.get(position) ;
        }
}
```

First Question

What are the `mFileList == null ? 0 : mFileList.size();` and `mFileList == null ? null : mFileList.get(position);` mean ??

Second Question

If I want to modify the code in the above from type object to int , how to do ?

from

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return mFileList == null ? null : mFileList.get(position) ;
    }
```

To

```
@Override
    public Integer getItem(int position) {

        return ???
            //what should I return for?
    }
```

Does somebody can help me to answer these two question ?

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: this is if else statement. if `mFileList == null` then return `null` else return  `mFileList.get(position)`

Comment: android is not a programming language. The keyword null is a Java keyword and, not to be polemical, I think that one should learn Java before learning android programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java ternary (immediate if) evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978324/java-ternary-immediate-if-evaluation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mFileList == null ? 0 : mFileList.size(); and mFileList == null ? null
>   : mFileList.get(position); are Turnary operators. Here is the [link](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018)

If you want to do another way do like this:

```
@Override
public Integer getItem(int position) {
    if(mFileList == null)
       return 0;
    else
       return mFileList.size();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First question: it's a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a), essentially an inline if-else. `foo ? bar : baz` first evaluates `foo` and if the result of that expression is `true`, `bar` is used and `baz` otherwise.

Second question, don't modify `getItem` method signature. It's expected to be the way it is. All classes in Java extend `Object` so you can return `Integer`s as well. The method seems to be good the way you have it now, no need to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

```
return mFileList == null ? null : mFileList.get(position)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(mFileList == null)  
    return  null;
else
   return mFileList.get(position);
```