# Ternary operator evaluating conditional statement while condition not met

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

I have written some code; here the relevant snippets:

```
@NonNullByDefault
public class Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>
{
    protected NUMERAL value;
    @Nullable
    protected LITERAL literal;
    [...]
```

I have overwritten my `equals()`method as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(@Nullable Object object)
{
    if(object == null) return false;
    if(object == this) return true;

    if( object instanceof Score)
    {
        return ((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getValue().equals(value) &&
                literal == null ? ((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getLiteral() == null : literal.equals(((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getLiteral());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically, the idea is that a `Score` may only have a numeric value in which case the `literal` is null. I have written some unit tests and get a null pointer exception with the code below:

```
[....]
Score<Float, String> score = new Score<>(0.0f);
Score<Float, String> anotherScore = new Score<>(1.0f, "One");
[....]

assertFalse(score.equals(anotherScore));
```

If I am not mistaken, shouldn't short-cutting in `equals` prevent anything after the `&&` from being executed as the first expression is already `false`? Furthermore, why the exception? As the conditional is true, I would expect the expression of the ternary to be evaluated and the conditional expression skipped. From what I have read in the specifications, this should be the behaviour. Furthermore, I found this question: [Java ternary (immediate if) evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978324/java-ternary-immediate-if-evaluation) which should lend some more leverage to my thought process.

Maybe I have overlooked something rather obvious but I am out of ideas. Maybe you can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It short-circuits alright, but not quite the way you want it to. `&&` has a higher precedence than the ternary `?:` - therefore this (indentation, line breaks and comments added to clarify)

```
((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getValue().equals(value) &&
literal == null
    ? ((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getLiteral() == null
    : literal.equals(((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getLiteral())
```

actually means this:

```
//the first line as a whole is the condition for ?:
((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getValue().equals(value) && literal == null
    ? ((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getLiteral() == null
    : literal.equals(((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getLiteral())
```

This means, in practice, that if the first part of the condition is `false` but `literal` is `null`, you automatically enter the `:` part of the expression where you call `literal.equals`, causing the `NullPointerException`.

The fix is simple: add parentheses to tell Java which way you want stuff to be evaluated:

```
((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getValue().equals(value) && 
(literal == null 
    ? ((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getLiteral() == null
    : literal.equals(((Score<NUMERAL, LITERAL>) object).getLiteral()))
```

Comment: @durron597, OP seems like a coder who can definitely figure that out for themselves but I guess it won't hurt. Including it right away.

Comment: I agree, but a future reader might have this problem yet might not be that smart :). I +1ed before commenting anyways; thanks for making the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll test it first thing on Monday. Can't believe I made such an obvious mistake! At least I learned a valuable lesson, again! ;)

Comment: @EricTobias, no problem. I had to check the precedence order too for this answer!

Comment: Worked like a charm, Cheers!