# Why does returning null (where a boolean is expected) as the result of a ternary operator compile?

Tags: java, ternary-operator

A curiosity that I've just noticed, rather than a problem.

I'm not allowed to write

```
public boolean x() {
  return null;
}
```

or this:

```
public boolean x() {
  if (DEBUG) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

but I am allowed to write

```
public boolean x() {
  return DEBUG ? true : null;
}
```

Why is this? (It appears to throw an NPE if the "else" branch is taken.)

Comment: Thanks @Thilo. To clarify: the question is, why isn't the ternary construct rejected in the same way as the other two examples?

Comment: @MichaelKay Again, just out of curosity, have you tried `public boolean x() {
  if (DEBUG) {
    return true;
  } 
    return null;
  
}` ?

Comment: possible dupplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978324/java-ternary-immediate-if-evaluation ?

Comment: in java8 it's even more complicated. see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/-ap9v5MDO_4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the [jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) states:

> The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:
>       If the second and third operands have the same type (which may be the null type), then that is the type of the conditional expression.
>       If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

This means java allows `null`, since it can be used to generate  an instance of `Boolean`, which can be unboxed to `boolean` (read the section about [boxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) in the jls for more info). But since the `Boolean` instance is initialized `null`, the call to `booleanValue()` will result in a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator sees that you have the two options `true` and `null`, so it has to use autoboxing and type itself (i.e. the result of the *conditional operator*) as `Boolean` (which in turn gets unboxed again automatically by the `return`).

The exact rules are a bit complicated, you can find them [in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

At run-time you then get a NullPointerException during the unboxing of the `return` value.

Answer (score 0):

See [JLS-15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows: ... If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the conditional expression is that reference type.
>
> ...
>
> At run time, the first operand expression of the conditional expression is evaluated first. If necessary, unboxing conversion is performed on the result.
>
> The resulting boolean value is then used to choose either the second or the third operand expression:
>
> ...
>
> The chosen operand expression is then evaluated and the resulting value is converted to the type of the conditional expression as determined by the rules stated above.
>
> This conversion may include boxing (§5.1.7) or unboxing (§5.1.8) conversion.

So - essentially - your `null` is boxed into a `Boolean`.

Comment: But the other is not a reference type. Read on in the JLS for the rule that applies here.